# Disabling Spring JMS Auto configuration in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

In my spring boot application i configure two different instances of MQQueueConnectionFactory (different id) as it is a need of the application. For that i have added ibm client jars.

I have also added spring-jms dependency in my code as i wanted JmsTemplate etc classes. After adding this dependency, JmsAutoConfiguration finds JmsTemplate in classpath and tries to configure beans. In this process, it tries to inject bean of type ConnectionFactory and this is where the code fails and i start getting the error. Below is the code from JmsAutoConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(JmsTemplate.class)
@ConditionalOnBean(ConnectionFactory.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(JmsProperties.class)
@Import(JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.class)
public class JmsAutoConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JmsProperties properties;

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private DestinationResolver destinationResolver;
```

Do i have a facility to switch off JmsAutoconfiguration feature of spring boot by any chance? If not then what is the alternative solution for this?

Comment: Note to future Apache Tomcat Java WAR deploying viewers, if you see an error with `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9f8a2d0.CGLIB$SET_THREAD_CALLBACKS([Lorg.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback;)` in `catalina.out`, you can try out some of these answers below.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can add the auto configurations, which you want to disable, to the SpringBootApplication annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = JmsAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Comment: Or: `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = JmsAutoConfiguration.class)`

Answer (score 19):

FYI, use this to disable **ActiveMQ**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = ActiveMQAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Answer (score 16):

if want to control it via the properties (in this case a application.yml) then you can do something like this.

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case it worked after excluding both classes :

```
 @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={JmsAutoConfiguration.class, ActiveMQAutoConfiguration.class})
```