# Spring Boot: Disabling JmsAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jboss, cloud, openshift

My Springbootloader all looks like

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.xxx.aaa.api",exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class, JmsAutoConfiguration.class})
```

@EnableJms
public class ApplictionBoot extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(ApplictionBoot.class);
}

@Bean
public InternalApiInitializer internalApiInitializer() {
    return new InternalApiInitializer();
}

@Bean
  public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(
      ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
      DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    return factory;
  }
@Bean
  public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws JMSException {
        return new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }

 @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = 
                      new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        return factory;
     }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(ApplictionBoot.class, args);

}
```

}

Even after disabling Auto Config loader, i'm getting stopped by

```
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.CrshAutoConfiguration$CrshBootstrapBean in Module "deployment.application.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/CrshAutoConfiguration$CrshBootstrapBean (Module "deployment.application.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
```

tried with options provided in [Disabling Spring JMS Auto configuration in Spring Boot Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275088/disabling-spring-jms-auto-configuration-in-spring-boot-application) but of dead end, can anyone plese help me out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your startup is failing because of `CrshAutoConfiguration`, which i believe has nothing to do with `JmsAutoConfiguration`.

add `CrshAutoConfiguration.class` also in exclude configuration