# Error creating bean with name 'jmsConnectionFactory' - NullPointerException - Spring Boot Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

I am writing a reporting service to receive messages from Azure Service Bus topic subscriptions.
I followed this initial guide - [How to use the Spring Boot Starter for Azure Service Bus JMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-service-bus#receive-messages-from-a-service-bus-subscription) and simply configured the `@JmsListener` in my service files to not specify a `JmsConnectionFactory` so that it would fall back to the default, however this returned the error logs shown below, with `jmsConnectionFactory` Bean returning a `NullPointerException`.

I subsequenly looked at [Bauldung - Getting Started with Spring JMS](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jms)
 and [Baeldung - Messaging with JMS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/) for guidance on how to configure the `jmsConnectionFactory` when the initial implementation wouldn't run but had no luck with any of the suggestions mentioned in the articles above as it was still returning the error logs below.

I then had a dig here on StackOverflow and found this question - [Spring Boot - Error creating bean with name 'jmsConnectionFactory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52223365/spring-boot-error-creating-bean-with-name-jmsconnectionfactory), which then pointed to this question - [Disabling Spring JMS Auto configuration in Spring Boot Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275088/disabling-spring-jms-auto-configuration-in-spring-boot-application/41326790#41326790) and this lead me to exclude `ServiceBusJMSAutoConfiguration::class` in my `@SpringBootApplication`. This actually worked but I find it a little strange that I should need to exclude this class, and feel as though there is something else I may be doing wrong.

I'm basically looking for any insight on whether what I'm doing is normal practice or if there is a better way to go about this set-up, as I'm not particulary a fan of this - `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = [ServiceBusJMSAutoConfiguration::class])`. To me it seems like some kind of hack to solving an underlying issue. Any help/opinions on this would be greatly appreciated.

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

ReportingServiceApplication.kt

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = [ServiceBusJMSAutoConfiguration::class])
class ReportingServiceApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<ReportingServiceApplication>(*args)
}
```

Sample Listener - AwardEditEventService.kt

```
interface AwardEditEventService {
    fun receiveMessage(awardEditEvent: AwardEditEvent)
}

@Service
class AwardEditEventServiceImpl(
    val awardEditEventsRepository: AwardEditEventRepository
) : AwardEditEventService {

    @JmsListener(
        destination = "reporting",
        subscription = "AwardEdits"
    )
    override fun receiveMessage(awardEditEvent: AwardEditEvent) {
        awardEditEventsRepository.save(awardEditEvent)
    }
}
```

build.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.4.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.10.RELEASE"
    id("com.diffplug.gradle.spotless") version "4.0.1"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.72"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.3.72"
}

group = "com.test.service"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    // Kotlin
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    // Spring Boot
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")

    // Flyway
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")

    // App Insights
    implementation("com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter:2.6.1")
    implementation("com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-logging-logback:2.6.1")

    // Azure Service Bus
    implementation("com.microsoft.azure:azure-servicebus-spring-boot-starter:2.2.5")
    implementation("com.microsoft.azure:azure-servicebus-jms-spring-boot-starter:2.2.5")

    // Snowflake
    implementation("net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.12.12")

    // Postgres (For Local Development)
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")

    // Test
    testImplementation("com.h2database:h2:1.4.200")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.6.0")
    testImplementation("org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:2.2")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}
```

Here are the logs for the initial error -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/microsoft/azure/spring/autoconfigure/jms/ServiceBusJMSAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jmsConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.test.service.reporting.ReportingServiceApplicationKt.main(ReportingServiceApplication.kt:13) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jmsConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.jms.ConnectionStringResolver.getServiceBusKey(ConnectionStringResolver.java:30) ~[azure-spring-boot-2.2.5.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.jms.ServiceBusJMSAutoConfiguration.jmsConnectionFactory(ServiceBusJMSAutoConfiguration.java:40) ~[azure-spring-boot-2.2.5.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.jms.ServiceBusJMSAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9ce4d56.CGLIB$jmsConnectionFactory$3(<generated>) ~[azure-spring-boot-2.2.5.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.jms.ServiceBusJMSAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9ce4d56$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$99b2393f.invoke(<generated>) ~[azure-spring-boot-2.2.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.jms.ServiceBusJMSAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9ce4d56.jmsConnectionFactory(<generated>) ~[azure-spring-boot-2.2.5.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify pricing-tier for the service bus as indicated below:

```yaml
spring:
  jms:
    servicebus:
      connection-string: Endpoint=sb://xxx
      idle-timeout: 30000
      pricing-tier: Standard
```

Answer (score 0):

`spring.jms.servicebus.pricing-tier = XXXXX` is very important in your configuration. You should replace `XXXXX` with your pricing-tier.